# UINavigationBar subclass detect when navigation item title changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using a custom subclass of UINavigationBar with my `UINavigationController` by using: `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`.

Needless to say, in this subclass I need to monitor and update an additional interface element contained within my navigation bar subclass when the title of the presented navigation item changes. I have considered using KVO for this and observing the navigation items `title` property and updating as a when that changes but I was wondering if perhaps there was a better way. Would subclassing `UINavigationController` perhaps give me some more leeway to take control or monitor this function? I am interested to hear your thoughts on this one and whether or not there is a better way to go about this?

---

**To elaborate:** I am overiding some methods for example `layoutSubviews`. In this method when the navigation item has just been pushed onto the stack it doesn't yet have a title. This is because the title is set in the view controllers `viewDidLoad` which won't be executed until the view is loaded which has not happened yet. As such even though the navigation item has been pushed the title is still `nil` until it is changed in the presented view controllers `viewDidLoad`. This is what I want to be notified of when the navigation item is changed **after** it has been pushed onto the navigation stack.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about what you want? Under what circumstances does the title of the navigation item change? Do you mean it can have different titles for the same controller, or are you talking about when a new controller is pushed?

Comment: @rdelmar It relates to when the title of the navigation item is set, I've elaborated a bit more and edited by question